# Is converting a maximization algorithm into a minimization one a matter of changing max to min?

Tags: algorithm

This might come across as a silly question but I am curious to know if given a maximization algorithm and asked to get the dual (minimization version), it is just a matter of converting all max's into min's and doing other basic adjustments?

If yes, are there any problems where this would not be the case? If not, is there a good intuitive reason why this does not work?

Comment: Is there a minimum version of the Knapsack problem?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Sorry! Typed it out in a hurry. I edited my question.

Comment: I was actually thinking it might be the counter-example you're looking for.  Minimizing the value of the objects in the knapsack is trivially easy, but it's a much different algorithm than flipping the signs on the solution to the maximization knapsack problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, maximization and minimization problems are basically the same. The solution for `max(f(x))` is the same as `-min(-f(x))`.

When searching game trees this relation is used for example to convert a [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) search into a [negamax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) search. This has the advantage that instead of writing two functions, one for maximizing your score and another for minimizing the opponent's score, you write a single maximizing function but flip the sign of the result of the evaluation function when it's the other person's move.

Comment: [Game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) is about modeling social behavior using mathematics, not studying actual games.  There is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory), but people don't call this *"game theory"* - usually they just call it *"game AI"*  *(The minimax article further befuddles things by combining the decision theory theorem with the related algorithm by the same name.  Really, these should be separate articles).*

Comment: Just because it is simple does not mean it is dumb :) The minimax algorithm is the backbone of every chess algorithm, including the one used by Deep Blue to beat world champion Garry Kasparov in 1997.  An even simpler concept (Neural Networks) forms the basis of some of the most powerful computer learning/recognition systems on earth. *(PS. I do not mean to disagree with you - you already have my +1)*

Comment: @Mark Byers, I am wondering why `max(f(x))` is not just `min(-f(x))`? why do we need to also put a negative sign before the `min`? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your maximization algorithm works.  Numerical algorithms that need gradients will probably do more than `max` and `min`, and other complexities can come up.

However, there is indeed a very easy fix.  Maximizing a function `f(a,b,c)` is equivalent to minimizing `-f(a,b,c)`.  So just negate result of the function.

Comment: Maybe I am too picky but `max f = \min -f` is not true. Maybe you meant to say that `argmin f = argmin -f`?

Comment: @MrYouMath, you mean `max f = -min -f` ?  And that seems pretty dang true to me. Counterexample?

Comment: You said that "maximizing a function $f$ is equivalent to minimizing -f$ and that is not true.

Comment: @MrYouMath and I asked you for a counterexample.  Do you have one?  Or are you just being pedantic about the sign of the result?

Comment: I am being more precise about the sign of the result. Your statement is not correct as it is written at this moment. This is a math question and should be answered with more precision. That is the only thing that I wanted to say. If you don't care about it leave it as it is.

Comment: @luqui your statement is not correct. MrYouMath is right.

Answer (score 2):

It works if the problem is obviously symmetrical like finding the maximum vs. a minimum on a 2D-surface. However, since you are quoting the Knapsack problem: that is a whole other class of problems, the optimum cannot be found by applying some max() function in a greedy manner to a vector.

Comment: Great observation. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Knapsack *can* be stated as a maximization problem: 'Given these 20 items with these properties, maximize the value of the items you can fit into this knapsack'. Or equivalently 'minimize the value of the items you have to leave behind'.

Comment: @Mark Byers: That's the same problem.  Solving one gives you a direct route to the solution to the other (just look at what items are left over).  Compare that to `array.min()` vs. `array.max()`, which doesn't have the same property.

Comment: It is not a matter how **if a human can formulate it verbally as a maximization problem**. It is a matter of if you can formulate a function max(x,i) that can iteratively maximize value(x). Only in those cases you can simply replace a max() function with a min() function and hope to find at least locally optimal minimums.